# Retrieve an element from a given index in the biggest list value of a JSON

Tags: python, json

Here are the instructions:

> Giving a randomly-generated JSON string. Find the longest list and
> return its key, followed by a dash ('-'), followed by the element at
> index 1
>
> ```
> {
>   "agistment": "nonpromulgation",
>   "gastroparietal": 4599,
>   "ryotwar": [
>     "mealies",
>     "sophistress",
>     "money",
>     "astraeid"
>   ],
>   "pranava": [
>     "rosinesses",
>     "basis"
>   ],
>   "loomer": 581.6,
>   "bangalay": "orthopnea",
>   "inflexive": 3367,
>   "spinelles": [
>     "druith",
>     "pseudomonades",
>     "nonrhythmically",
>     "ischiocavernosus",
>     "operettist"
>   ],
>   "articulator": 2805.3,
>   "preempted": [
>     "equvalent",
>     "mesoderms",
>     "idlers"
>   ],
>   "unfractiously": [
>     "semitextural",
>     "stilyaga",
>     "coddle",
>     "identism"
>   ],
>   "synkinesia": 4993,
>   "linoleum": "overcram",
>   "nations": "colleagueship",
>   "lithonephria": "presoaked",
>   "subpartitioned": "tiresomeness",
>   "triternately": [
>     "postaxial",
>     "nonimmune",
>     "eopaleozoic",
>     "maledict",
>     "ritzily",
>     "whisperation"
>   ],
>   "etoile": "nonvesting",
>   "decussorium": [
>     "tocusso",
>     "butterfingered",
>     "sizeman",
>     "duetted",
>     "misthrew",
>     "untextually",
>     "splenotyphoid",
>     "acmispon"
>   ],
>   "novelties": "hypersthenite",
>   "aesop": [
>     "sabadinine",
>     "tangency"
>   ],
>   "potlatching": [
>     "lucrific",
>     "tupaia",
>     "dedenda",
>     "burglarise",
>     "tanagroid",
>     "grewsomely",
>     "lipotype",
>     "squarable",
>     "withholdal",
>     "antidotes"
>   ],
>   "preformistic": "broadsiding",
>   "papovavirus": 3917,
>   "hurri": [
>     "catcall"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Note : the index and JSON is randomly generated each time I do the lab, so I have to write generalized code. Here's what I came with first :

```
ind = 1 #raw data for better understanding

json_data = json.loads(challenge_input) #challenge_input is the json above sent in the lab

biggest_length = 0 #will store the biggest length of the list of a value in the JSON

for key, value in json_data.items():
    if type(value) == list: # check if the value of the key is a list
        list_length = len(value) # store the length
        if list_length > biggest_length: # check if the list is bigger than the existent biggest list
            biggest_length=list_length # store the biggest list length
            list_value = value # store the value from the json into a variable
            list_key = key # stoer the value of the key from the json into a variable
            
result=list_key + "-" + list_value[ind] #output


# {} =
send_data_to_server(client_socket, result) #send the result to the server to validate the lab
```

Here's the output of my code :

```
Your answer was on time but incorrect: - Your answer was "potlatching-tupaia", the expected answer was "potlatching-"tupaia""
```

My first idea was that my JSON value was maybe parsed to a string or given a bad format. I've tried to "bypass" this, by manually adding --> ". As you would expect, didn't work. :

```
result=f'"{list_key}-"{res[ind]}""'
```

Output:

```
Your answer was on time but incorrect: - Your answer was "ultralegality-"reservoired"", the expected answer was "ultralegality-"reservoired""
```

As you see, bypassing doesn't work.

I don't know what's wrong. Is it the way I retrieve the data in the JSON, which leads it to being in another format ? (like string format?) Is is the way that I display my data ? The Lab seems to check the data and the type, but I don't know any more solutions. I've tried almost every way of display the data (str(), f"{}", ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `f'{list_key}-{json.dumps(res[ind])}'`. This should handle the data types as expected, wrapping strings in quotation marks but not ints, and handling arbitrary elements like lists or dicts.

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks a lot